# iOS , How to know which account was used to buy app in ios appstore?

Tags: ios

I know that apple do not permit to get programmatically details about phone's owner account. I can't have the email or any others personal informations, it's all about privacy.

If i want to identify a device instead of a user account, there is a similar situation, but in this case Apple is trying to fill this "lack of funcionality". From ios 11 there is a system that create a way to identify ( without show any personal informations ) a device.

[DeviceCheck](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck?language=objc)

So my question is: There is something similar but centered to user's identification ?

I don't need to collect/see personal info (lik emails,name,ecc..) , i need only an unique id that identify an apple user account. I have to store it in my system to check "if a user has did an action".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do that. If you need to uniquely identify your users, create a `UUID` when your app starts the first time after installation.